# How To Add Button To Commerce POS Command Pane?

Tags: commerce

My module needs to implement a custom payment workflow. I want to add a button to the Commerce POS command pane to perform a task, then modify the order entity according to the result of the task.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the hook [hook_commerce_pos_commands()](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_pos/tree/commerce_pos.api.php?id=0ec1ca33da675243d1af874b7dd858df81b73933).

Comment: This will add a button by default because buttons are generated for all commands. A more direct way is to implement hook_commerce_pos_buttons()